# How to use regex in vim to toggle case for all characters in a file

Tags: regex, linux, vim, replace

I have a file which has the following text

```
Lorem IpSuM is SIMPLY duMMy TeXt of the PrINtinG and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's stanDaRd dummy text ever since the 1500s,
whEn an unknown printer took a galley of type and sCrAMBled it to MakE a type specimen BoOk.
```

After toggling the case of all the characters the text file should look like:

```
lOREM iPsUm IS simply DUmmY tExT OF THE pRinTINg AND TYPESETTING INDUSTRY.
lOREM iPSUM HAS BEEN THE INDUSTRY'S STANdArD DUMMY TEXT EVER SINCE THE 1500S,
WHeN AN UNKNOWN PRINTER TOOK A GALLEY OF TYPE AND ScRambLED IT TO mAKe A TYPE SPECIMEN bOok.
```

I am using the following regex pattern:

```
%s/\<\([A-Z\s\]+\)\>/\L&/
```

But vi editor is throwing an error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: \<\([A-Z\s\]+\)\>/\L&/
```

What is the correct pattern for toggling case of all characters in a file at once using regex in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why going for regex and `:s`, if you can do <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Shift+v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>?

If you have to do it in a script, you can use `:normal`:

```
:normal ggVG~
```

---

Well, if you really want to go for `:s`, you can do this

```
%s/\a/\=submatch(0) >= 'a' && submatch(0) <= 'z' ? toupper(submatch(0)) : tolower(submatch(0))/g
```

(I suspect there's a way to write `submatch(0) >= 'a' && submatch(0) <= 'z'` more concisely, but I don't know of it, or it simply doesn't come to my mind. [romainl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73245900/5825294) shows that way.)

Answer (score 2):

```
%s/\<\([A-Z\s\]+\)\>/\L&/
```

is not a "pattern", only that part is:

```
\<\([A-Z\s\]+\)\>
```

Note that Vim is complaining about this pattern:

```
\<\([A-Z\s\]+\)\>/\L&/
```

which means that Vim couldn't spot the separator between the search part and the replacement part. This is likely due to this backslash:

```
\<\([A-Z\s\]+\)\>/\L&/
          ^
```

Removing it makes for a proper substitute command but Vim still says it can't find the pattern. Let's deconstruct it to see why…

- `\<` and `\>` mean that you want your pattern to be anchored at the beginning and end of a word.
- `\(` and `\)` delimit a capture group but you don't use one in the replacement so it is unnecessary.
- `+` is a literal `+`, if you want "one or more of the previous atom", you need `\+`. This is probably where the extraneous backslash comes from.
- `\s` means that you want to include a space in your pattern, which is a bit contradictory with `\<` and `\>`.

It *looks* like you are trying to match words made of only uppercase characters, which doesn't make sense given your stated goal.

And then there is the `\L` in the replacement part, which makes the text lowercase. If you want to **toggle** casing, turning all uppercase characters into lowercase is useless because then you can't toggle the case of the previously lowercase characters anymore as everything is now lowercase. This is not a good strategy.

Using a normal mode command, as suggested by the other answer, sounds like a much better strategy.

As for substitutions, there is no built-in "toggle" equivalent of `\L` and `\U` so you need to beef up your replacement part with a bit of vimscript:

```
:%s/./\=submatch(0) =~ '\L' ? toupper(submatch(0)) : tolower(submatch(0))
```

where…

- `\=` tells Vim to use the result of an expression as replacement,
- what follows is a ternary condition where we return the uppercase version of the match if it is lowercase or the lowercase version if it is not.

See `:help sub-replace-special`, `:help sub-replace-expression`, `:help string-functions`.